# Hibernate remove object

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to ensure if it is ok. I have 2 entities. Let's say A and B. A has B, like this:

```
class A {

@OneToOne
@Column(name ="B_ID")
B b;
}

B hasn't A.

Let's say set B to A like this:

new A().setB(BInstance);
```

COMMIT. Now, after awhile I want to delete B by ID. Let's say I have B id and want to delete it. So QUESTION: IF I delete B (which A has), A entity remove B entity reference too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`A` is the owning side and has the join column in it's table. If you delete a record for `B` while an `A` record still has the foreign key, you should receive a `PersistenceException` because of a constraint violation and your transaction should be rolled back.